# Как преобразовать строку к виду телефонного номера?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Изучаю SwiftUI. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в TextField при вводе номера накладывалась маска("+X (XXX) XXX-XXXX"). Сама функция есть, и она работает. Не могу разобраться, как и где мне ее вызвать, чтобы при изменении строки, пользователь сразу видел изменённую строку.

```
static func format(with mask: String, phone: String) -> String {
        let numbers = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        var result = ""
        var index = numbers.startIndex

        for ch in mask where index < numbers.endIndex {
            if ch == "X" {

                result.append(numbers[index])
                index = numbers.index(after: index)

            } else {
                result.append(ch)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот минимальный пример с использованием вашего кода, здесь используется также код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58841655/3004003) для перемещения курсора при вводе в конец текста, иначе он остается всегда в начале текста и получается, что каждая новая цифра вводится первой. Правда при таком подходе все равно остается проблема перескока курсора в конец текста при исправлении цифры в середине.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    let mask = "+X (XXX) XXX-XXXX"

    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {

        let textChangedBinding = Binding<String>(get: {
            Self.format(with: self.mask, phone: self.text)
        }, set: {
            self.text = $0
        })

        return TextFieldContainer(mask, text: textChangedBinding)
    }

    static func format(with mask: String, phone: String) -> String {
        let numbers = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        var result = ""
        var index = numbers.startIndex

        for ch in mask where index < numbers.endIndex {
            if ch == "X" {
                result.append(numbers[index])
                index = numbers.index(after: index)
            } else {
                result.append(ch)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

/************************************************/

///
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/58841655/3004003
///
struct TextFieldContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    private var placeholder : String
    private var text : Binding<String>

    init(_ placeholder:String, text:Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.text = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> TextFieldContainer.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldContainer>) -> UITextField {

        let innertTextField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        innertTextField.placeholder = placeholder
        innertTextField.text = text.wrappedValue
        innertTextField.delegate = context.coordinator
        innertTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad // << added by schmidt9

        context.coordinator.setup(innertTextField)

        return innertTextField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldContainer>) {
        uiView.text = self.text.wrappedValue
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: TextFieldContainer

        init(_ textFieldContainer: TextFieldContainer) {
            self.parent = textFieldContainer
        }

        func setup(_ textField:UITextField) {
            textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        }

        @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.parent.text.wrappedValue = textField.text ?? ""

            let newPosition = textField.endOfDocument
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

На вопрос **как?**:
Занести возвращаемое функцией значение в объектную переменную, к примеру в `yourphoneobject`.
Кстати функция format принимает еще один строковый аргумент `mask`
поэтому на вход его то же подаем!

На вопрос **где?**:
Там где нужно вернуть обработанный нашей функцией телефонный номер через объект обращаемся к ней:

```
var phonenumber: String = "<источник>"
var phonenmask String = "<источник>"

var yourphoneobject = <имя класса где, находится функция format>()
yourphoneobject.format(phonenmask, phonenumber)
```

далее `yourphoneobject` применяем или подставляем где требуется вернуть обработанный номер.

Подробнее почитать можно [Объектно-ориентированное программирование](https://metanit.com/swift/tutorial/3.1.php)
и [Объекты и классы](http://idev-swift.ru/documentation-on-the-russian-swift/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE-swift-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B/)